# How to persistently save structures_graph in a databse/file?

Tags: php, data-structures, graph

I intend to use the library [Structures_graph](https://pear.php.net/package/Structures_Graph/docs/latest/) to create a directed graph data structure in PHP.
My problem is that

1. I cannot find how to save these graphs persistently (either in a file/database)
2. In case you do know how to save it persistently, please also tell me how do I use the saved data back again so that it can be used with this library.

To put it in another words, if there is a graph created in one session it needs to be saved so that it can be used in another session. All this to be done while I'm using the above said library.

I am aware that I can run a for loop for all the nodes and check who they are connected to and thus create a matrix that I can save in a file. And use this matrix in the next session to initialize my nodes and weights. But I am wondering since someone has taken the effort to make graphs so simple by writing this library, could there be an easy way (library) to do what I intend to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store and retrieve just about any PHP structure using serialize() to turn it into a string and unserialize() to get the original structure back.

Comment: Thanks that helped. Any idea how do I add weight to the edges in created using this library?

Comment: Do you mean heavier borders on the nodes? I'm not familiar with GoJS, but they seem to have lots of examples of nodes with heavier borders. Probably part of Node Template Maps.